# JS Mouse click and Drag Instead of Horizontal Scroll bar preventing click

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to drag a carousel of images linked with href to a separate page.

this is the code I found it works

```
let mouseDown = false;
let startX, scrollLeft;
const slider = document.querySelector('.carousel');

const startDragging = (e) => {
  mouseDown = true;
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
}

const stopDragging = (e) => {
  mouseDown = false;
}

const move = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!mouseDown) { return; }
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const scroll = x - startX;
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scroll;
}

// Add the event listeners
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', move, false);
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopDragging, false);
```

but I have an issue:

when I release the drag, the page fires the link. How do I prevent that?

thanks

Comment: Try adding `e.preventDefault();` to the other two functions, the default event is being fired by one of the other handlers